# exception in acquiring data - C# with OracleDB

Tags: c#, oracle11g

```
static public void ConnectAndQuery()
        {

            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("State: " + conn.State);
                Console.WriteLine("Connection String: " + conn.ConnectionString);

                OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                command.CommandText = sql;

                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string myField = (string)reader["MYFIELD"];
                    Console.WriteLine(myField);
                }
            }

        }
```

The connection is established and working open but I get `IndexOutOfRangeException` when trying to acquire the data from the DB. The exception is caught on

```
string myField = (string)reader["MYFIELD"];
```

I looked for info about the OracleDataReader and the command in order to understand the reader, but... does it store the data acquired in an array or any other sequence ? Why am I getting the `IndexOutOfRangeException` and why does the reader require an argument in the `[]` brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not have a field that is called MYFIELD. Remember that the field names are case sensitive... Try using an index instead i.e. reader[0]